# Hiding a UIImageView in viewWillAppear and Unhiding in viewWillDisappear 'flicker' problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uiimageview

I have a logo imageView within the root view controller of my navigation controller's navigationBar, added as a subview, and when I present a detail controller (in this case a webView controller), I animate and set the logo's alpha to 0. Now, in the webView controller's viewWillDisappear, I animate that same logo's alpha back to 1.0.

The problem though is that when you use the interactive edge gesture for popping, but instead choose to cancel the pop (return back to the webView controller) The logo's alpha briefly appears back to 1.0 when the webView appears fully and then goes back to an alpha of 0 like its supposed to, appearing as an annoying 'flicker' if you will.

I'm lost how to solve this, and I appreciate any help/pointers offered.

Code and screenshot of issue:

[image]

@implementation WebViewController

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    UIImageView *view = (UIImageView *) [self.navigationController.navigationBar viewWithTag:1];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.35];
    view.alpha = 0.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    UIImageView *view = (UIImageView *) [self.navigationController.navigationBar viewWithTag:1];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.35];
    view.alpha = 1.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: That is just as bad as the flicker, as the image view isn't visible at all until the presenting view controller is fully visible.

Comment: Is there no other way to do what I want? I really like the logo fading in and out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you can't change things in the middle of an animation unless the animation logic running on the GPU has been designed to handle that kind of change.

`UINavigationController` has already started an animation, and nothing can change while that animation is running. Your animation would need to have been setup before the navigation controller's one.

If you want this level of control, do not use `UINavigationController` at all. It is designed to be used a certain way, and you're trying to use it in other ways. Even if you figure out a way to make it work you will have bugs. It's highly unlikely your app will function properly on iOS 8 if you do this kind of stuff.

Write your own replacement for `UINavigationController` that behaves the way you want, and then any animation you can dream up will be easy to implement.

However, keep in mind Apple's engineers know iOS programming better than anyone else in the world and it took them *years* to write `UINavigationController`. If your replacement is going to be as good, you will have to put in that much work. Up to you if it's worth the effort.